# Track yaml file changes in nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Nodemon does not reload after yaml files change.
How can I configure *nodemon* to reload the server when a `yaml` file changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure nodemon to watch your `yaml` files in two ways:

1. By **extension**
2. With the **file path**

---

#### By Extension

The [documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/#specifying-extension-watch-list) states that:

> By default, nodemon looks for files with the `.js`, `.mjs`, `.coffee`, `.litcoffee`, and `.json` extensions.
>
> You can specify your own list with the `-e` (or `--ext`) switch

Like so:

```
nodemon -e yaml server.js
```

*Note: the dot before the extension `.yaml` is not mandatory, you can omit it.*

Now when any `.yaml` file changes, your server will restart.

---

#### With the file path

You can use the flag `-w` (or `--watch`)

The [wiki](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/wiki) says:

> Watch directory "dir" or files. use once for each directory or file to watch.

Like so:

```
nodemon -w file1.yaml -w file2.yaml server.js
```

You'll see something like

```
[nodemon] watching: file1.yaml file2.yaml
```

Now when one of these two files changes it will restart, but it wont' watch another `.yaml` file if it is not specified.

Comment: This extension flag prevents nodemon from watching unnecessary source code files that may not affect a running node.js script, but you can customize it as you want.

Answer (score 10):

*nodemon* can also be configured using a config file.

Create a file named *nodemon.json* and place it in the root of your project, for example where your project's *package.json* file already is.

If you want to add .yaml to the default extensons watched, put this code in your ***nodemon.json***

```json
{
  "ext": ".js, .mjs, .coffee, .litcoffee, .json, .yaml"
}
```

Comment: Nice!  Only option that worked for me trying to watch .env files.

Answer (score 2):

With the `-e` option you can listen to the changes of most file extension.
It is shorthand for `--ext` as pointed out in the comments.

`nodemon -e .yaml index.js`

Comment: you mean `--ext`

Comment: try `nodemon --help`, I see `-e --ext` and `-x --exec`.

Comment: yeah they might have made a mistake in the github docs you can make a pull request :D

Comment: the github doc doesn't say `--exec` for `-e` but the sentence is ambiguous. You should try to format your answer and add some documentation about the flag for completeness and you'll have some upvotes

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon),

By default, nodemon looks for files with the `.js`, `.mjs`, `.coffee`, `.litcoffee`, and `.json` extensions. However, you can specify your own list with the -e (or --ext) switch like so:

```
nodemon -e js,pug
```

Now nodemon will restart on any changes to files in the directory (or subdirectories) with the extensions .js, .pug.

Answer (score 0):

I case you want to watch/track for multiple file types, like .ts and .yaml do this

`nodemon -e ts -e yaml`

this will not only watch changes for typescript files but also for yaml files.

and in case your compiled build contains yaml files
you have to ignore that files from nodemon to watch otherwise it will get into the loop of compiling and watching the same files indefinitely, so use this

`nodemon -e ts -e yaml --ignore build/` considering build is the directory(in the same directory where package.json file is present) where the compiled typescript files and other files resides.